# Can't apply background gradient

Tags: html, css

I created a basic form in HTML and an `app.css` file to style the page.
When I set a gradient as the `background-image` it doesn't show on page:

```css
HTML,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #e0c3fc 0%, #8ec5fc 100%);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="today">
      <div
        class="titlu"
        style="color: black; margin-top: 5.5%; font-size: 65px;"
      >
        Autentificare
      </div>

      <form id="form" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">email:</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" />
          <span id="msg"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="parola">Parola:</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            name="parola"
            class="form-control"
            id="parola"
          />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-block elev">
            Autentifica-te
          </button>
        </div>
        <div
          class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show"
          style="display: none;"
        ></div>
      </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

When I open the page in live server it show this:
[image]

Comment: Use the inspector and verify 1) if the gradient is actually applied and 2) if a child of the body has a background applied that covers the gradient

Comment: Have you included the css file?

Comment: your missing including css in html. Try with inline css. it working for me

Comment: by any chance are you making all your element position:absolute?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I make this but it doesn't work

Comment: no, I am asking if your are making them absolute, if so it's the issue and I can bring a duplicate

Comment: I set position to absolute but the color doesn't appear

Comment: you didn't get me: I am not asking you to *set* position;absolute, I am asking you if you are *already setting* position:absolute. If you are doing then it's the issue

Comment: I understand I didn't set position to absolute

Comment: Maybe that some other css is overwriting it and it's not actually getting applied. Try inspecting `body` element. You can give a shot to use this css with `!important` E.g. `background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #e0c3fc 0%, #8ec5fc 100%) !important`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradients belong to the image data type, they can only be used where images can be used. For this reason, linear-gradient property won't work on background-color property and other properties that use the color data type.

The correct declaration will be

CSS

```
body {
background: linear-gradient(120deg, #FF0000 0%, #0000FF 100%);
}
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Comment: he's not using background-color but background-image which is valid for gradient

Comment: @TemaniAfif  What he wants to do doesn't include a gradient overlay. Which will only show when he wants to include an image in the background which is not the case.

Comment: @CosminCiolacu You are welcome. Just note that linear-gradient only works with background-image if you will put an image with an overlay effect.

Answer (score 1):

Try using RBG values instead of hex. And setting the height of the background to 100% like so.

```
    HTML,
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height:100%;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(224, 195, 252, 0),rgba (142, 197, 252, 1));
    }
```

Comment: I used RGB values and set the height to 100 %, but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the percentages, making it look like this

`background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #e0c3fc, #8ec5fc);`

and use RGBA instead.

Also, I think there is a typo in your title.

Answer (score -1):

```
body{
  background: #0e0c3f;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(120deg, #0e0c3f 0%, #08ec60 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%, #0e0c3f), color-stop(100%, #08ec60));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(120deg, #0e0c3f 0%, #08ec60 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(120deg, #0e0c3f 0%, #08ec60 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(120deg, #0e0c3f 0%, #08ec60 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(120deg, #0e0c3f 0%, #08ec60 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0e0c3f', endColorstr='#08ec60', GradientType=1 );
  }
```

You can use this CSS code as you need to webkit to support diffrent browser you might be using diff browser can i know which browser you are using.?

you can use free gradient generator websites to generate gradients code who support every browser or try to accumulate every browser.

Comment: @CosminCiolacu https://codepen.io/nikitesh/pen/qBBvYXx check this snippet